# Add property, that doesn't show up when object is printed

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I'm cycling through a list adding a new field to each item in it like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < returnList.length; i++) {
    returnList[i].eligible = true;
};
```

Then if i do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < returnList.length; i++) {
    console.log(returnList.eligible);
};
```

It returns "true" multiple times.

However if I then do:

```
console.log(returnList);
```

Then it returns (I'll just give an example of one of the objects):

```
{ _id: 557ff7dab10a9e8029cf9baa,
WGS84:{ longitude: 0.028586996883792574,
 latitude: 51.363584078860356 },
free: false,
approved: true,
organisationName: 'Test Organisation',
__v: 0,
polygonLineCoordinates: [],
organisationLocation: { postCode: 'BR2 6BP' },
opportunities: [],
events: [],
supportAreas: [] }
```

This clearly doesn't have the eligible element in. I would just like to know what is going on!

Adam

Comment: could you create jsfiddle?

Comment: The code you've shown works fine for me. What have you *not* shown?

Comment: The code is part of a much larger project here is the whole view from express http://pastebin.com/GKGqqgN7

Answer (score 1):

You can define a non [enumerable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) property. The simplest solution is to use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
var obj = {};
obj.someProp = true;
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'eligible', {writable:true});
obj.eligible = true;
console.log(obj.eligible); // logs true
for (var k in obj) {
  console.log(k); // only logs "someProp"
}
```

```js
var obj = {};
obj.someProp = true;
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'eligible', {writable:true});
obj.eligible = true
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('pre')).innerHTML = "obj.eligible = "+obj.eligible;
console.log(obj.eligible); // logs true
for (var k in obj) {
  console.log(k); // only logs "someProp"
}
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('pre')).innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj)
```

Comment: I dont understand why it has to be a non enumerable property surely its just adding a normal property like any other

Comment: Well, if you say it's not enumered... But there are too many missing points in your question, you should make it clearer, starting by reproducing the behavior you describe in a fiddle/snippet.